# How do you find the root directory so that a path works across multiple computers?

Tags: python, windows, path, python-2.7

I am writing a program that sets up a file path that I use to store data. The format is as follows

```
c://users/username/.../endingpath
```

When i switch computers the username is changed. Is there a way or a method that specifies what the username is for the specific computer I am working on? Or is there an even better way of making the path computer independent?

I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under Windows, there are several pre-defined environment variables that you can look at.  One of those is `USERNAME`.

So:

```
import os
user_name = os.getenv("USERNAME")
```

Windows also defines environment variables for some directories.  If your file should be stored in the user's personal home directory (on Windows 7, this is: `%SystemDrive%\Users\{username}`) you can use `USERDATA` or `USERPROFILE`.  This is better than trying to build your own path with the user name.

@Matteo Italia pointed out that `APPDATA` is probably the best one to use; that is specifically a directory for applications to store their data files.  This makes sense to me; I think he is right.

So:

```
import os
appdata_dir_name = os.getenv("APPDATA")
```

I found a list of Windows environment variables in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples_from_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: I'd say that for keeping your application settings the best is to store your configuration file under %APPDATA% (if there are multiple files, create a subdirectory named after your application and store them there).

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I think you are right and I updated the answer to include your input.  Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You should find out the appropriate directory using the [SHGetKnownFolderPath function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can probably use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to use that function.

Comment: Why do you recommend this instead of checking the environment variable `USERPROFILE`?  This would work but seems like overkill.

Comment: The environment variables aren't the place to look for that info. It might be duplicated there but that's a convenience, not a contract. If a program has access to the API you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified Windows 7, I'm assuming you're using it on all the computers the program will be executed on, so, you can just use `'%UserProfile%/.../endingpath'`. (Or `'%UserProfile%\\...\\endingpath'`.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_Home_Directory_per_Operating_System

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
os.path.expanduser(path)
```

make sure the path is relative with either ~ or ~user in front of the path name

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html